# How to avoid caldroid to swipe left to a previous month?

Tags: android

I'm using the caldroid library and I want that the user can't left swipe  to a previous month.
I find how to avoid user to swipe right or left. But I want only avoid left swipe.

I tried to put a different onTouchListener to the InfiniteViewPager but didn't work.
And I tried to didn't add the previous month to the InfiniteViewPager but didn't work.

How I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should make your own custom OnTouchListener which can detect if the user swipes from left to right.

Check this Question
[How to handle right to left swipe gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures)